# Remove special characters from encrypted phone field in salesforce

Tags: apex, formula, custom-field, field-level-encryption

I've **encrypted phone field** is there and it referred in formula field. I need to remove special character in the formula field (tried with SUBSTITUE) but it is not allowing to change because it's a encrypted field. Could anyone suggest how to do it.

Comment: Recommend reviewing [Supported Operators, Functions, and Actions](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.security_pe_formulas.htm&type=5) for using Encrypted Data in Formulas

Comment: Thanks but I don't see, if in formula field contains (322)-(233)-(1091) and it should return 3222331091. I was able to do it for normal fields but encrypted fields not allowing.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, SUBSTITUE() is not a [supported Function](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.security_pe_formulas.htm&type=5) for using Encrypted Data in Formulas.

There does not seem to be a direct/simple way to achieve what you are looking for. The workaround would be to create a physical field instead of a formula field, and populate it via trigger or workflow, then encrypt it.